# C# MongoDB Upsert - 'BsonValue(Guid) is obsolete: 'Use the BsonBinaryData constructor instead and specify a Guid representation'

Tags: c#, mongodb, guid, upsert, obsolete

I'm new to MongoDB and am trying to create an Upsert:

```
public void UpsertRecord<T>(string collectionName, Guid id, T record)
    {
        var collection = db.GetCollection<T>(collectionName);

        var result = collection.ReplaceOne(
            new BsonDocument("_id", id),
            record,
            new ReplaceOptions { IsUpsert = true });
    }
```

But I get the following warning in Visual Studio:

> 'BsonValue.implicit operator BsonValue(Guid) is obsolete: Use the
> BsonBinaryData constructor instead and specify a Guid representation'

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: also taking tim cury's 'Intro to MongoDB with C#'? 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to fix it this way:

```
public void UpsertRecord<T>(string table, Guid id, T record)
    {
        BsonBinaryData binData = new BsonBinaryData(id, GuidRepresentation.Standard);
        var collection = db.GetCollection<T>(table);

        var result = collection.ReplaceOne(
            new BsonDocument("_id", binData),
            record,
            new ReplaceOptions { IsUpsert = true });
    }
```